# How can I estimate the probability of a random member from one population being "better" than a random member from a different population?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose I have samplings from two distinct populations.  If I measure how long it takes each member to do a task, I can easily estimate the mean and variance of each population.

If I now hypothesise a random pairing with one individual from each population, can I estimate the probability that the first is faster than the second?

I do have a concrete example in mind: the measurements are timings for me cycling from A to B and the populations represent different routes I could take; I'm trying to work out what the probability is that picking route A for my next cycle will be faster than picking route B.  When I actually do the cycle, I've got another data point for my sample set :).

I'm aware that this is a horribly simplistic way to try to work this out, not least because on any given day the wind is more likely to affect my time than anything else, so please let me know if you think I'm asking the wrong question...

Comment: This is can be done via simple binomial testing & @Macro has a good answer.  However, one issue is with the samples themselves: is there anything that could affect your decision to take route A or route B?  In particular, do you like to take route A when the roads are dry, the wind is at your back, and dinner's waiting?  :)  Just be careful of anything that could affect outliers in either set or that could bias the samples in some way.  For instance, try setting up your sampling plan ahead of time, with consideration for any need to vary (e.g. safety).

Comment: One other consideration: Suppose that you have two routes with very similar means and neither dominates the other in terms of the probability that it will be faster.  E.g. one is always either 10 or 20 minutes, while the other is always precisely 15 minutes.  You may find it better to penalize greater uncertainty (e.g. standard deviation), or to favor one that is more likely to take less than some threshold of time.  Your question as-is is fine; I am merely suggesting a future refinement.

Comment: The statistical question is fine, but if you want to work out the probability which route is faster, I should suggest measuring the lengths of the routes. If the terrain is not hilly then the shorter route will always be faster.

Comment: If wind is an important factor, and if the wind speeds are related for the two routes, then it would seem that a person would need information about the dependence between A and B to answer the question accurately.  You would need bivariate data for that, and it's hard to ride two paths at the same time.  You could enlist someone else to help you collect data, but then would need to account for the variability between riders.  In the case A and B are independent, the answers below are great.

Comment: Put another way: if I'm trying to decide which path to take, one's through a tunnel, one's through a field, and the wind's blowing like crazy, I may very well choose the field even if it does horribly worse on average.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great answers :).  Of the routes I have in mind, one involves climbing over a hill while the other goes around it.  Wind may be a confounding factor, but I hope that with enough random samples, it'll average out -- I'm not looking for a perfect estimator -- I know I'd never manage to get that.  My intent is to choose which route I'll cycle next time using the probabilities I've generated from my previous cycles: discarding old data should mean that I wind up cycling the 'better' route more often, even if which route is best changes over time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Solution

Let the two means be $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ and their standard deviations be $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$, respectively.  The difference in timings between two rides ($Y-X$) therefore has mean $\mu_y - \mu_x$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}$.  The standardized difference ("z score") is

$$z = \frac{\mu_y - \mu_x}{\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}}.$$

Unless your ride times have strange distributions, **the chance that ride $Y$ takes longer than ride $X$ is approximately the Normal cumulative distribution, $\Phi$, evaluated at $z$.**

#### Computation

You can work this probability out on one of your rides because you already have estimates of $\mu_x$ etc. :-).  For this purpose it's easy to memorize a few key values of $\Phi$: $\Phi(0) = .5 = 1/2$, $\Phi(-1) \approx 0.16 \approx 1/6$, $\Phi(-2) \approx 0.022 \approx 1/40$, and $\Phi(-3) \approx 0.0013 \approx 1/750$.  (The approximation may be poor for $|z|$ much larger than $2$, but knowing $\Phi(-3)$ helps with the interpolation.)  In conjunction with $\Phi(z) = 1 - \Phi(-z)$ and a bit of interpolation, you can quickly estimate the probability to one significant figure, which is more than precise enough given the nature of the problem and the data.

#### Example

Suppose route $X$ takes 30 minutes with a standard deviation of 6 minutes and route $Y$ takes 36 minutes with a standard deviation of 8 minutes.  With enough data covering a wide range of conditions, the histograms of your data might eventually approximate these:

[image: Two histograms]

*(These are probability density functions for Gamma(25, 30/25) and Gamma (20, 36/20) variables. Observe that they are decidedly skewed to the right, as one would expect for ride times.)*

Then

$$\mu_x = 30, \quad \mu_y = 36, \quad \sigma_x = 6, \quad \sigma_y = 8.$$

Whence

$$z = \frac{36 - 30}{\sqrt{6^2 + 8^2}} = 0.6.$$

We have

$$\Phi(0) = 0.5; \quad \Phi(1) = 1 - \Phi(-1) \approx 1 - 0.16 = 0.84.$$

We therefore estimate the answer is 0.6 of the way between 0.5 and 0.84: 0.5 + 0.6*(0.84 - 0.5) = approximately 0.70.  (The correct but overly precise value for the Normal distribution is 0.73.)

There's about a 70% chance that route $Y$ will take longer than route $X$.  Doing this calculation in your head will take your mind off the next hill.  :-)

*(The correct probability for the histograms shown is 72%, even though neither is Normal: this illustrates the scope and utility of the Normal approximation for the difference in trip times.)*

Comment: if you have iid realizations from each distribution then what is the advantage of using the normal approximation rather than a monte carlo re-sampling approach (my answer) to estimating $P(X>Y)$?

Comment: @Macro: if the data can be reduced to summary statistics for the Q of interest, one can store less data...  just a thought.

Comment: Sorry, my brain was fried by heat & I missed the obvious answer.  You are each answering different questions.  The bootstrap method you gave estimates $P(X > Y)$, while @whuber is considering the difference in the mean times, which isn't the same.  It isn't too hard to construct a case where option $Y$ is shorter than option $X$ 60% of the time, but the mean for $Y$ is greater than the mean for $X$.

Comment: FWIW: @whuber is describing Student's t-test for the difference in means between two samples with different standard deviations.

Comment: @Iterator Not quite.  This is not a Student t test.  Moreover, I *am* answering the question about the probability, not about the difference in mean times.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify where the test statistic compares the random variables $X$ and $Y$ vis-a-vis $P(Y > X)$?  ;-)  I see $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$, indicating analysis of $E(Y-X)$, which is a bit different from $E(\textrm{sign}(Y-X))$ or, alternatively, $E(\mathbf{1}_{Y-X})$ .  (NB: traditionally, the estimates of the expectation are denoted $\bar{X}$ and $\bar{Y}$, as they are based on samples.  It's important to be clear about what the random values are - they're not $E(X)$ or $E(Y)$.)

Comment: @Macro The advantage is twofold: ease of computation and helping inform our understanding of the situation.  There is nothing the matter with Monte Carlo resampling; it's a fine approach and it's more accurate than the approximations shown here; but due to its mindless, brute force nature, it may fail to help us see and understand the essence of the problem.  Obviously--because it requires access to all the data--it's not something one is going to muse over during a long ride :-).

Comment: @Iterator Simple: I'm computing the probability of the event $Y \ge X$ when $(X,Y)$ has a bivariate normal distribution (with zero correlation).  That's exactly what the question calls for.  For this problem, I see little merit in distinguishing estimates from parameters, so I have used parameters, but I have endeavored to distinguish the random variables $X$ and $Y$ from the parameters.  Perhaps you are reading things in my exposition that aren't there.

Comment: This may help clarify (unfortunately, it renders poorly in comments - semicolons added abundantly):
    x = 1:10;
    y = c(1:5,20);
    x1  = sample(x, 10000, replace = TRUE);
    y1  = sample(y, 10000, replace = TRUE);
    mean(y1 > x1);
    mean(y1 - x1)

Comment: Hmmm, the OP never mentioned bivariate normal.  :)

Comment: I strongly agree that you have a good solution, just to a different problem.  The graph is quite nice, btw.  What software produced it?

Comment: @Iterator, the software is I suspect Mathematica, since whuber always uses Mathematica to produce the graphs in this site :)

Comment: @mpiktas: Thanks!  It is a good promo for Mathematica's graphs; I'll have to keep it in mind if I want to do some nice graphs like that.  :)

Comment: @Iterator, whuber makes a very good advertising for Mathematica :) I myself was more impressed with symbolical computing capabilities of Mathematica, nice graphs can also be produced with R thanks to ggplot2.

Comment: @whuber (+1), I like your answer, it's well done, and you said explicitly in the comments that you assumed zero correlation.  For this particular problem, though, is that reasonable?  The OP said perhaps the wind is the deciding factor, and presumably wind speeds are related for the two paths.  Furthermore, the OP can't estimate $r$ without riding both paths simultaneously (or collecting some sort of other bivariate data).  It would seem that the problem is more difficult than one a single rider can solve.

Comment: Thanks, @whuber, this is the answer to the question I'd been trying to ask :).

Comment: @G. Jay Correlation is impossible because it is never the case that both routes are simultaneously taken: it's either one or the other.  Your concern about wind nevertheless has merit in another sense: if the *choice* of route depends upon some factor, that will affect the results.  However, it affects them by biasing the empirical distributions of times for each route; it still cannot introduce any correlation.

Comment: @mp I have been impressed by the ggplot examples that have appeared on this site.  I'm not trying to promote *Mathematica*; it just happens to be a good tool for working out mathematical questions and therefore it's convenient to use it to make quick illustrations, rather than using other software for that purpose.

Comment: @whuber only one path being observed at a time doesn't mean the correlation doesn't exist. And (despite the title) the question reads like a hypothetical race with oneself, to me at least.  All of this is academic, though, because your answer was great to start with and the OP has made it clear that you answered the question of interest to him.

Answer (score 6):

My instinctive approach may not be the most statistically sophisticated, but you may find it to be more fun :)

I would get a decent-sized sheet of graph paper, and divide up the columns into time blocks. Depending on how long your rides are - are we talking about a mean time of 5 minutes or an hour - you might use different sized blocks. Let's say each column is a block of two minutes. Pick a color for route A and a different color for route B, and after each ride, make a dot in the appropriate column. If there's already a dot of that color, move up one row. In other words, this would be a histogram in absolute numbers.

Then, you would be building a fun histogram with each ride you take, and can visually see the difference between the two routes.

My sense based on my own experience as a bike commuter (not verified through quantification) is that the times will not be normally distributed - they would have a positive skew, or in other words a long tail of upper-end times. My typical time is not that much longer than my shortest possible time, but every now and then I seem to hit all the red lights, and there's a much higher upper-end. Your experience may be different. That's why I think the histogram approach might be better, so you can observe the shape of the distribution yourself.

PS: I don't have enough rep to comment in this forum, but I love whuber's answer! He addresses my concern about skewness pretty effectively with a sample analysis. And I like the idea of calculating in your head to keep your mind off the next hill :)

Comment: +1 For creativity.  Actually, your idea is on the path toward practical utility.  It would be quite a bit more interesting to use one of the biking tracking sites (I forget which one now, but do add, if you know) to track segment times.  If the OP were to come back to CV or StackOverflow with a question about plotting segment time and get a density associated with it, it would be a fabulous statistical exercise - GIS, statistical visualization, and density functions, oh my!  :)

Comment: I have used Google MyTracks on my phone to track biking segments. I find that the phone is not great at it as it tends to be a power-suck on a device not optimized for it. Garmin (and others) make GPS devices specifically targeted at runners and bikers to track time spent on routes and provide neat charts in an online interface. I don't use a dedicated GPS device myself, but some of my friends use them to share routes on facebook.

Comment: Here is an [example](http://connect.garmin.com/activity/108317870) of what Garmin device produces. The problem with the charts is that they are already heavily pre-processed, smoothing, etc. Also there is no convenient way to import the data to R for example. But as dedicated device it does its job splendidly, I cannot imagine running or biking without it.

Comment: +1 Note that not much skew comes from hitting the red lights (unless they are timed): collectively, they usually only add some Gaussian noise to the time distribution.  (Computing its variance is another mental exercise you can do on the next hill.)  In practice the skew comes from non-Gaussian variation in the few important factors that control the entire ride: weather, how you're feeling, with whom you're riding, and the occasional accident/detour/traffic jam etc.

Comment: Now that I think about it some more, another very important factor is the time of day. The traffic lights act very differently at peak traffic times - much longer greens for the higher-traffic road. In off-peak times, the lights tend to cycle quickly, defaulting to green for the high-traffic road, but quickly changing when I press the crossing button or a car activates the sensor.

Comment: As I tend to ride on the low-traffic road and am often crossing the high-traffic road, this means longer red light wait times at peak hours. I'm trying to think how this would affect the distribution, and my behavior comes into play as well - I try to avoid peak traffic times because of this.

Comment: It's complex, because you can adjust your riding to keep some momentum going through the lights.  To zeroth order, if lights have random phases, a light that is red for $r$ seconds and green for $g$ seconds causes us to wait $r^2/(6(g+r))$ seconds. Encountering $n$ of them will therefore create an approximately normal distribution of delays with mean $r^2n/(6(g+r))$ and variance $r^3n(1/2-r/(3(g+r)))/(3(g+r))$. This acts to increase the travel time by the mean and then to convolve it with Gaussian noise of the given variance.  That's how you can quantify changes in $g$ and $r$ during the day.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the two data sets are $X$ and $Y$. Randomly sample one person from each population, giving you $x,y$. Record a '1' if $x > y$ and 0 otherwise. Repeat this many times (say, 10000) and the mean of these indicators will give you an estimate of $P(X_{i} > Y_{j})$ where $i,j$ are randomly selected subjects from the two populations, respectively. In R, the code would go something like:

```
#X, Y are the two data sets
ii = rep(0,10000)
for(k in 1:10000)
{
   x1 = sample(X,1)
   y1 = sample(Y,1)
   ii[k] = (x1>y1) 
}

# this is an estimate of P(X>Y)
mean(ii)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but you could simplify it by removing the `for` loop: let `x1 = sample(X, 10000, replace = TRUE)` and `y1 = sample(Y, 10000, replace = TRUE)` and then calculate `mean(x1 > y1)` along with `mean(x1 == y1)` - to get a sense of the # of times the values are equal.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the loop was unnecessary but I wanted the logic underlying the approach to be abundantly clear. Your code would certainly produce the same results.