# How can I estimate the probability of a random member of one population being "better" than a random member from multiple different populations?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a set of multiple population distributions, with a known mean and standard deviation for each. I'm trying to find the probability for a given one of these distributions of a random member being "better" than a randomly pulled member for each of the other distributions at the same time. [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14774/how-can-i-estimate-the-probability-of-a-random-member-from-one-population-being) solves this problem for comparing it with one distribution and seems easy enough to implement, but I'm having trouble finding out how to do this in comparing with more than one distribution. Would I simply find the probability of "beating" each other distribution and then multiply it out? My gut reaction is that this wouldn't work because of them being pulled at the same time, "beating" one shouldn't be independent of "beating" others, as one really good value should be enough to beat all others. For feasibility's sake, I'd only have less than 25 distributions, on average probably closer to 15.

Comment: You may want to look at: (1) A discussion of the properties of the [Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Properties). Especially, the part about comparisons with other tests. (2) A discussion of the two-sample [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) in terms of empirical CDFs.

Answer (score 0):

**Probabilities.** If you want to evaluate $P(X < Y),$ then the answer by @whuber in your link gives an exact solution for normal $X$ and $Y$ and reasonable approximations for random variables from some other families of distributions.

For example, if $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(100,10)$ and independently
$Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(90, 15),$ then it is easy to see that
$$P(X < Y) = P(D = X < Y) = P(D < 0) = 0.2895,$$ where $D \sim
\mathsf{Norm}(10, \sqrt{10^2 + 15^2}).$ [Computation in R.]

```
pnorm(0, 10, sqrt(10^2+15^2))
[1] 0.2895499
```

Where an exact computation is not feasible, it is easy to get a
good approximation by simulation, as follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
d = replicate(10^6, rnorm(1,100,10) - rnorm(1,90,15))
mean(d < 0)
[1] 0.289842
```

Are values $X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(3,1)$ generally larger than values
$Y \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(2,1)?$ As above. we can evaluate 
$P(X > Y) = 0.687 \pm 0.001$ by simulation:

```
set.seed(4321)
d = replicate(10^6, rgamma(1,3,1) - rgamma(1,2,1))
mean(d > 0)
[1] 0.687279
2*sd(d > 0)/1000
[1] 0.0009272039
```

**Majorization.** However, parts of your question suggest you are interested in testing
whether one distribution majorizes ('beats') another. So I will
discuss two relevant tests.

*ECDFs and the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:*

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rgamma(500, 3, 1);  y = rgamma(500, 2, 1)
plot(ecdf(x), col="blue", 
     main="ECDFs: GAMMA(3,1) [blue] and GAMMA(2,1)")
lines(ecdf(y), col="red")
ks.test(x, y)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y
D = 0.306, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Below. the ECDF of $X$ (blue) lies to the right of the ECDF of $Y,$ Indicating that the former distribution has generally larger values.

[image]

Note: A one-sided test is also possible; see the R documentation on `ks.test` to
see the syntax, and also for a remark about possible confusion in the use
of the `alt` parameters `less` and `greater`.

*Two-sample Wilcoxon tests:*

Here are results of two-tailed (first) and one-tailed Wilcoxon signed rank tests.

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 174430, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

wilcox.test(x, y, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 174430, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

The notches in the sides of the boxplots below are calibrated
for comparing locations of data in *two* boxplots. Nonoverlapping
notches suggest significantly different locations.

[image]

***Smaller sample sizes:*** 
Sample sizes may be smaller than above and need not be equal. The K-S test
is generally less powerful than the Wilcoxon test. (The K-S test statistic is based on the maximum vertical discrepancy between
ECDFs, which is not great in the example below.)

```
set.seed(415)
x = rgamma(20, 3, 1);  y = rgamma(25, 2, 1)
ks.test(x, y, alt="g")$p.val
[1] 0.08829099
wilcox.test(x, y, alt="g")$p.val
[1] 0.007959596
```

[image]

Note: The 'stairstep' ECDF of a sample displays its values in sorted order.
For sample size $n$ the ECDF increases by $1/n$ at each sample value.
If $k$ observations are tied at a value, then the size of the jump there is $k/n.$